# Grails custom URL mapping for user nicknames

Tags: grails, controller, url-mapping

I have a custom URL name requirement.

Each user will have a custom page and it must be at the root of the domain

For example: http:www.bemdireto.com.br/eduardo

This will conflict with default controller's mapping.

The application already exists, so I cannot change the controllers url.

We have came up with the following code

```
 "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
     controller = {
    def log = Logger.getLogger('br.com.fisgo.UrlMappings')

    log.trace "Verifying if a broker hot site or controller"

    def uri = delegate.getCurrentRequest().getRequestURI()
    log.info "Acessando uri: ${uri}"

    UrlMappingUtil.handleBrokerHotSiteController(uri, {owner ->
       params.owner = owner
       })
    }

        action = {
            def uri = delegate.getCurrentRequest().getRequestURI()
            UrlMappingUtil.handleBrokerHotSiteAction(uri)
        }
    }
```

The method UrlMappingUtil.handleBrokerHotSiteController will tell controller and nickname apart.

The problem is: the method is being executed 7 times for each request.

I can't find the reason why.

I've noticed that the urlMapping is called 3 times before de UrlMappingsFilter and 4 after.

Answer (score 0):

link generators are tied to URLMappings, this is true when not using the default CachingLinkGenerator.

Some of your code in UrlmappingUtil might also impact it.

Check the number of links in your page. If the observation is still the same, you may want to implement your own urlmappingevaluator.

Comment: Even though I removed all links from the page it still execute the function 7 times. What else can trigger URLMappings? or where else is the link generators called?

Comment: Check your UrlMappingUtil code then if removing the links had no impact. Link generators are called for hyperlink generation.

Comment: No luck on that yet. This process is slowing down the page

Comment: try to change the log level to debug in your Config.groovy, it might help you trace the method calls and related classes.